# how to get the images in a 2nd slider to be the same size as the first slider

Tags: html, css, slider

I am creating two slider carousels on the same page however the images in the second slider are all different sizes and are not contained to the same width like the first carousel. Can I please get some advice on how the images on the second slider can match the first slide? The image attached shows the mismatch in the two sliders Thank you

```css
html {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

body{
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    place-items: centre;
}

.slider {
    height: 250px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 90%
    display: grid;
    place-items: centre;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slider2 {
    height: 250px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 90%
    display: grid;
    place-items: centre;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slide-track {
    display: flex;
    width: calc(250px * 18);
    animation: scroll 40s linear infinite;
}

.slide-track2 {
    display: flex;
    width: calc(250px * 18);
    animation: scroll 40s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes scroll {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 9));
    }
}

@keyframes scroll2 {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 9));
    }
}
.slide{
    height: 200px;
    width: 250px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 15px;
    perspective: 100px;
}

img {
    width: 100%
}
img:hover {
    transform: translateZ(20px);
}


.slider::before,
.slider::after {
   background: linear-gradient (to right, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,
   rgba(255,255,255,0) 100):
   content: '';
   height: 100x;
   position: absolute;
   width: 15;
   z-index: 2;
}

.slider::before {
   Left: 0;
   top: 0;
}

.slider::after {
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   transform: rotateZ(180deg);

}

.slider {
    height: 250px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 90%
    display: grid;
    place-items: centre;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slide-track {
    display: flex;
    width: calc(250px * 18);
    animation: scroll 40s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes scroll {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 9));
    }
}

.slide{
    height: 200px;
    width: 250px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 15px;
    perspective: 100px;
}

img {
    width: 100%
}

img:hover {
    transform: translateZ(20px);
}


.slider::before,
.slider::after {
   background: linear-gradient (to right, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,
   rgba(255,255,255,0) 100):
   content: '';
   height: 100x;
   position: absolute;
   width: 15;
   z-index: 2;
}

.slider::before {
   Left: 0;
   top: 0;
}

.slider::after {
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .slide-track {
    width: calc(80px * 20);
  }

  .slide-track2 {
    width: calc(80px * 15);
  }

  .slide {
    width: 80px;
  }

  @keyframes scroll {
    0% {
      transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(calc(-80px * 10));
    }
  }

  @keyframes scroll2 {
    0% {
      transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(calc(-80px * 5));
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Treasures</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/pricingstyle.css">

</head>
<body>
    <!--  Carousel 1    -->
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slide-track">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/shop/london-childrens-photographer-004-1226x818.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/gallery/20210818173514_IMG_3340.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/portraits/kmp-yorkshire-family-photography-9.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/gallery/20210422183251_IMG_1091 (1).jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/gallery/20220228142811_IMG_4632.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/gallery/20210806180418_IMG_2724 (1).jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/portraits/20220102171402_IMG_4272.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/family/20200209143046_IMG_8658.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/family/20210816122750_IMG_2928.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <!-- same 9 slides doubled (duplicate) -->
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/shop/london-childrens-photographer-004-1226x818.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/gallery/20210818173514_IMG_3340.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/portraits/kmp-yorkshire-family-photography-9.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/gallery/20210422183251_IMG_1091 (1).jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/gallery/20220228142811_IMG_4632.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/gallery/20210806180418_IMG_2724 (1).jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/portraits/20220102171402_IMG_4272.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/family/20200209143046_IMG_8658.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/family/20210816122750_IMG_2928.jpg'/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--  Carousel 2 -->
    <div class="slider2">
      <div class="slide-track2">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='https://codeconvey.com/Tutorials/global-images/image-1.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='https://codeconvey.com/Tutorials/global-images/image-2.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/shop/mountain.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='https://codeconvey.com/Tutorials/global-images/image-4.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/shop/photo-1603979649806-5299879db16b.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/shop/f115c6707855841a0f1d6297901bc676.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/shop/20210807_202006.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <!-- same 9 slides doubled (duplicate) -->
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='https://codeconvey.com/Tutorials/global-images/image-1.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='https://codeconvey.com/Tutorials/global-images/image-2.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/shop/mountain.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='https://codeconvey.com/Tutorials/global-images/image-4.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/shop/photo-1603979649806-5299879db16b.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/shop/f115c6707855841a0f1d6297901bc676.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/shop/20210807_202006.jpg'/>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hg27m.jpg)I am creating two slider carousels on the same page however the images in the second slider are all different sizes and are not contained to the same width like the first carousel. Can I please get some advice on how the images on the second slider can match the first slide? The image attached shows the mismatch in the two sliders
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There were some typos in the css (a few missing semi-colons and some colons where semi-colons should be). Also, I added min-height and min-width to the img class and added the img class to the @media screen and (max-width: 768px). I do not think this is completely what you want but hope it gets you started.

```css
html {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

body{
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    place-items: centre;
}

.slider {
    height: 250px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    display: grid;
    place-items: centre;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slider2 {
    height: 250px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    display: grid;
    place-items: centre;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slide-track {
    display: flex;
    width: calc(250px * 18);
    animation: scroll 40s linear infinite;
}

.slide-track2 {
    display: flex;
    width: calc(250px * 18);
    animation: scroll 40s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes scroll {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 9));
    }
}

@keyframes scroll2 {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 9));
    }
}
.slide{
    height: 200px;
    width: 250px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 15px;
    perspective: 100px;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    min-width:250px;
    min-height:250px;
}
img:hover {
    transform: translateZ(20px);
}


.slider::before,
.slider::after {
   background: linear-gradient (to right, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,
   rgba(255,255,255,0) 100);
   content: '';
   height: 100x;
   position: absolute;
   width: 15;
   z-index: 2;
}

.slider::before {
   Left: 0;
   top: 0;
}

.slider::after {
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   transform: rotateZ(180deg);

}

.slider {
    height: 250px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    display: grid;
    place-items: centre;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slide-track {
    display: flex;
    width: calc(250px * 18);
    animation: scroll 40s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes scroll {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 9));
    }
}

.slide{
    height: 200px;
    width: 250px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 15px;
    perspective: 100px;
}

img:hover {
    transform: translateZ(20px);
}


.slider::before,
.slider::after {
   background: linear-gradient (to right, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,
   rgba(255,255,255,0) 100);
   content: '';
   height: 100x;
   position: absolute;
   width: 15;
   z-index: 2;
}

.slider::before {
   Left: 0;
   top: 0;
}

.slider::after {
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .slide-track {
    width: calc(80px * 20);
  }
img {
    min-width:80px;
    min-height:80px;
    max-height:80px;
}
  .slide-track2 {
    width: calc(80px * 15);
  }

  .slide {
    width: 80px;
  }

  @keyframes scroll {
    0% {
      transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(calc(-80px * 10));
    }
  }

  @keyframes scroll2 {
    0% {
      transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(calc(-80px * 5));
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Marquee Infinite scrolling LOGO carousel</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/pricingstyle.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!--  Carousel 1    -->
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slide-track">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/shop/london-childrens-photographer-004-1226x818.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/gallery/20210818173514_IMG_3340.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/portraits/kmp-yorkshire-family-photography-9.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/gallery/20210422183251_IMG_1091 (1).jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/gallery/20220228142811_IMG_4632.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/gallery/20210806180418_IMG_2724 (1).jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/portraits/20220102171402_IMG_4272.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/family/20200209143046_IMG_8658.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/family/20210816122750_IMG_2928.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <!-- same 9 slides doubled (duplicate) -->
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/shop/london-childrens-photographer-004-1226x818.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/gallery/20210818173514_IMG_3340.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/portraits/kmp-yorkshire-family-photography-9.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/gallery/20210422183251_IMG_1091 (1).jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/gallery/20220228142811_IMG_4632.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/gallery/20210806180418_IMG_2724 (1).jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/portraits/20220102171402_IMG_4272.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/family/20200209143046_IMG_8658.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/family/20210816122750_IMG_2928.jpg'/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--  Carousel 2 -->
    <div class="slider2">
      <div class="slide-track2">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='https://codeconvey.com/Tutorials/global-images/image-1.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='https://codeconvey.com/Tutorials/global-images/image-2.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/shop/mountain.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='https://codeconvey.com/Tutorials/global-images/image-4.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/shop/photo-1603979649806-5299879db16b.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/shop/f115c6707855841a0f1d6297901bc676.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/shop/20210807_202006.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <!-- same 9 slides doubled (duplicate) -->
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='https://codeconvey.com/Tutorials/global-images/image-1.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='https://codeconvey.com/Tutorials/global-images/image-2.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/shop/mountain.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='https://codeconvey.com/Tutorials/global-images/image-4.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/shop/photo-1603979649806-5299879db16b.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/shop/f115c6707855841a0f1d6297901bc676.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/shop/20210807_202006.jpg'/>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help with this. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have use the right way the `calc` property multiplaying the width of the element for the number of images per slide. However in your example code it was wrong. first row has 18 images while second has 14, and You use same rule (18) for both.

As a counsel, I would never recomend to do a slider with just CSS unless, for exmaple, is a test from teacher to student, javascript shoud be used.

```css
html {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

body{
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    place-items: centre;
}

.slider {
    height: 250px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 90%
    display: grid;
    place-items: centre;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slider2 {
    height: 250px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 90%
    display: grid;
    place-items: centre;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slide-track {
    display: flex;
    width: calc(250px * 18);
    animation: scroll 40s linear infinite;
}

.slide-track2 {
    display: flex;
    width: calc(250px * 14);
    animation: scroll 40s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes scroll {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 9));
    }
}

@keyframes scroll2 {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 9));
    }
}
.slide{
    height: 200px;
    width: 250px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 15px;
    perspective: 100px;
}

img {
    width: 100%
}
img:hover {
    transform: translateZ(20px);
}


.slider::before,
.slider::after {
   background: linear-gradient (to right, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,
   rgba(255,255,255,0) 100):
   content: '';
   height: 100x;
   position: absolute;
   width: 15;
   z-index: 2;
}

.slider::before {
   Left: 0;
   top: 0;
}

.slider::after {
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   transform: rotateZ(180deg);

}

.slider {
    height: 250px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 90%
    display: grid;
    place-items: centre;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slide-track {
    display: flex;
    width: calc(250px * 18);
    animation: scroll 40s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes scroll {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 9));
    }
}

.slide{
    height: 200px;
    width: 250px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 15px;
    perspective: 100px;
}

img {
    width: 100%
}

img:hover {
    transform: translateZ(20px);
}


.slider::before,
.slider::after {
   background: linear-gradient (to right, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,
   rgba(255,255,255,0) 100):
   content: '';
   height: 100x;
   position: absolute;
   width: 15;
   z-index: 2;
}

.slider::before {
   Left: 0;
   top: 0;
}

.slider::after {
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .slide-track {
    width: calc(80px * 18);
  }

  .slide-track2 {
    width: calc(80px * 14);
  }

  .slide {
    width: 80px;
  }

  @keyframes scroll {
    0% {
      transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(calc(-80px * 10));
    }
  }

  @keyframes scroll2 {
    0% {
      transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(calc(-80px * 5));
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Treasures</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/pricingstyle.css">

</head>
<body>
    <!--  Carousel 1    -->
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slide-track">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/shop/london-childrens-photographer-004-1226x818.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/gallery/20210818173514_IMG_3340.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/portraits/kmp-yorkshire-family-photography-9.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/gallery/20210422183251_IMG_1091 (1).jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/gallery/20220228142811_IMG_4632.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/gallery/20210806180418_IMG_2724 (1).jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/portraits/20220102171402_IMG_4272.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/family/20200209143046_IMG_8658.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/family/20210816122750_IMG_2928.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <!-- same 9 slides doubled (duplicate) -->
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/shop/london-childrens-photographer-004-1226x818.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/gallery/20210818173514_IMG_3340.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/portraits/kmp-yorkshire-family-photography-9.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/gallery/20210422183251_IMG_1091 (1).jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/gallery/20220228142811_IMG_4632.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/gallery/20210806180418_IMG_2724 (1).jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/portraits/20220102171402_IMG_4272.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/family/20200209143046_IMG_8658.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/family/20210816122750_IMG_2928.jpg'/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--  Carousel 2 -->
    <div class="slider2">
      <div class="slide-track2">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='https://codeconvey.com/Tutorials/global-images/image-1.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='https://codeconvey.com/Tutorials/global-images/image-2.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/shop/mountain.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='https://codeconvey.com/Tutorials/global-images/image-4.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/shop/photo-1603979649806-5299879db16b.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/shop/f115c6707855841a0f1d6297901bc676.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/shop/20210807_202006.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <!-- same 9 slides doubled (duplicate) -->
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='https://codeconvey.com/Tutorials/global-images/image-1.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='https://codeconvey.com/Tutorials/global-images/image-2.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/shop/mountain.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='https://codeconvey.com/Tutorials/global-images/image-4.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/shop/photo-1603979649806-5299879db16b.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/shop/f115c6707855841a0f1d6297901bc676.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src='static/images/shop/20210807_202006.jpg'/>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for having a look over my code and for providing feedback